# Checking text of individual divs and changing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have repeats of the same code multiple times because of my PHP echoing the content out, and I want to interact with each div separately. It's hard for me to explain, but here's an example of the code repeated just twice. Hopefully it fully represents what I actually have...

```
<form id="favorite"><div id="images"><input type="submit" style="background-image: url(grey.png);" onclick="submit" value="" /></div></form>
<form id="favorite"><div id="images"><input type="submit" style="background-image: url(grey.png);" onclick="submit" value="" /></div></form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#favorite').submit(function() {
    var url = document.URL; 
    if(document.getElementById("images").innerHTML.indexOf("grey") != -1) {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#favorite").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               $('#images').html("<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(red.png);\" onclick=\"submit\" value=\"\" />"); 
           }
         });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#favorite").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
               $('#images').html("<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(grey.png);\" onclick=\"submit\" value=\"\" />"); 
           }
         });
    }
    return false; 
});
```

So, if I were to click the image for the top form, it works perfectly. It will run the PHP and it will change the image without refreshing. If I click the bottom image, it will run the PHP, but it will refresh the page and it won't change the image. So it seems like if I click the bottom one, it doesn't like the Javascript. I don't know if it's because it's looking at both of the forms since they have the same ID (which I can't fix since it could possibly have hundreds), or something else, which I don't see any problems. I'm guessing there's some way to do it using "this", but I'm unsure of how to use it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a few things. Your selector to bind the event only matches the first occurrence of `#favourite` as id's should be unique. You get around this by using an [**attribute equals selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

In addition, ensure you select each sub-element in the context of the current form, similar to this:

```
$('[id=favorite]').submit(function () {
    var $form = $(this);                 // the current form
    var $image = $('#images', $form)     // get images element in the context of current form
    var url = document.URL;

    if ($image.html().indexOf("grey") != -1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $form.serialize(),     // use current form, don't re-select
            success: function (data) {
                $image.html("<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(red.png);\" onclick=\"submit\" value=\"\" />");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $form.serialize(),     // use current form, don't re-select
            success: function (data) {
                $image.html("<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(grey.png);\" onclick=\"submit\" value=\"\" />");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user2693030: You are welcome. In addition in regards to your HTML string. If you use single quotes on the outside you don't need to escape the double quotes inside, similar to this: `var inputHtml = '<input type="submit" style="background-image: url(red.png);" onclick="submit" value="" />'; $image.html(inputHtml);` Makes it easier to read/maintain.

Comment: I mainly copied from my PHP, so that's why I did it that way, but I probably should have done it with single quotes like you said. Again, thank you.